# ASP.NET Identity cannot convert to IUserStore

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am creating a custom storage provider for an ASP.NET WebAPI, following the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity), and I'm currently reconfiguring Identity to use my UserStore. My custom database context is `SqlDataAccess`, and is set in `Startup.Auth.cs`, as per the documentation.

```cs
app.CreatePerOwinContext<SqlDataAccess>(GetDataAccess);
```

where `GetDataAccess` is a function which returns an instance of `SqlDataAccess` with a configuration.

```cs
private SqlDataAccess GetDataAccess()
        {
            var dataAccess = new SqlDataAccess(WebApiConfig.Configuration);
            return dataAccess;
        }
```

The issue is that in `IdentityConfig.cs` I have set up the `ApplicationUserManager` with

```cs
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore(context.Get<SqlDataAccess>()));
```

This is just as the documentation says, with the EntityFramework database context replaced with my SqlDataAccess and my own UserStore. This produces the error `Argument 1: cannot convert from'DataManager.Identity.UserStore' to'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore<DataManager.Identity.User>'   DataManager C:\Website\DataManager\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs`
My UserStore implements IUserStore from Identity so I cannot see why this problem would occur. If it's needed, my UserStore implementation is below, I have not yet connected it to my library.

```cs
using DataAccessLibrary.DataAccess;
using DataAccessLibrary.Storage;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace DataManager.Identity
{
    public class UserStore : IUserStore<User, string>, IUserRoleStore<User, string>, IUserPasswordStore<User, string>
    {
        ISqlDataAccess _db;

        public UserStore(ISqlDataAccess db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }


        public Task AddToRoleAsync(User user, string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task CreateAsync(User user)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task DeleteAsync(User user)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<User> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(User user)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(User user)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(User user)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(User user, string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task RemoveFromRoleAsync(User user, string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(User user, string passwordHash)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task UpdateAsync(User user)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the tutorial and/or assemblies you're using may be out of sync with the version of aspnet.identity you're using since the error message implies that you should implement `UserStore<TUser>` instead of `UserStore<TUser, TKey>`

Comment: Yes, I had to change UserStore to implement ```IUserStore<TUser>``` and that solved it. I didn't realise there were multiple UserStore interfaces.